# Python: List all possible paths in graph represented by dictionary

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, dictionary, nodes, traversal

I have a dictionary with keys representing nodes and values representing possible nodes that the key can traverse to.

Example:

```
dependecyDict = { 'A': ['D'], 'B': ['A', 'E'], 'C': ['B'], 'D': ['C'], 'G':['H']}
```

I want to create a new dicitonary, ChainsDict, that will contain all 'values' that each 'key' can traverse to by means of dependecyDict.

For example, the output of the program with this example will be:

```
ChainsDict = {'A': ['D', 'C', 'B','E'], 'B':['A','D','C','E'], 'C':['B','A','D','E'], 'D':['C','B','A','E'], 'G': ['H']}
```

I think using a recursive algorithm is the best way to go about making a solution and I tried modifying a shortest path traversing algorithm as follows:

```
def helper(dependencyDict, ChainsDict):path = []
    for key in dependencyDict:
        path = path + [(recursiveRowGen(dependencyDict,key))]
    for paths in path:
        ChainsDict[paths[0]] = paths[1:]
    print(finalLineDict)
def recursiveRowGen(dependencyDict,key,path = []):
    path = path + [key]

        if not key in dependencyDict:
        print("no key: ",key)
        return path
        print(dependencyDict[key])
        for blocking in dependencyDict[key]:
            if blocking not in path:
                newpath = recursiveRowGen(dependencyDict,blocking,path)
                if newpath:
                    return newpath             
    return path
```

This code however is having problems capturing the correct output when a key in dependecyDict has more than one value.
I found a hacky solution but it doesn't feel very elegant. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recursive solution:

## Code

```
def get_chain_d(argDict):
    def each_path(i,caller_chain):
        a=[]
        caller_chain.append(i)
        b = argDict.get(i,[])
        for j in b:
            if j not in caller_chain:
                a.append(j)
                a.extend(each_path(j,caller_chain))
        return a

    return {i:each_path(i,[]) for i in argDict}

dependecyDict = { 'A': ['D'], 'B': ['A', 'E'], 'C': ['B'], 'D': ['C'], 'G':['H']}

print(get_chain_d(dependecyDict))
```

## Output:

```
{'B': ['A', 'D', 'C', 'E'], 'A': ['D', 'C', 'B', 'E'], 'D': ['C', 'B', 'A', 'E'], 'C': ['B', 'A', 'D', 'E'], 'G': ['H']}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a graph traversal problem. You can represent each of your key as a node in a graph and its values are the nodes it is connected to.

You can do either Depth-first-search or breadth-first-search for graph. Of course, there's also an iterative and a recursive solution for each of these method. Here's an iterative implementation (I added a few conditionals to eliminate loops):

```
dependencyDict = { 'A': ['D'], 'B': ['A', 'E'], 'C': ['B'], 'D': ['C'], 'G':['H'] }
chainsDict = {}

for key in dependencyDict:
    currKey = key
    frontier = [key]
    visited = []
    while frontier:
        currKey = frontier[0]
        frontier.remove(currKey)
        if dependencyDict.get(currKey,0) and (currKey not in visited) and (currKey not in frontier):
            nodes = dependencyDict[currKey]
            frontier.extend(nodes)
            visited.append(currKey)
        elif currKey in visited:
            visited.remove(currKey)
        elif dependencyDict.get(currKey,0) == 0:
            visited.append(currKey)
    for i in visited:
        if i == key:
            visited.remove(i)
    chainsDict[key] = visited

print chainsDict
```

The result looks like:

```
{'A': ['D', 'C', 'B', 'E'], 'C': ['B', 'A', 'E', 'D'], 'B': ['A', 'E', 'D', 'C'], 'D': ['C', 'B', 'A', 'E'], 'G': ['H']}
```